# Change mixing parameters in likelihood

Tags: maximum-likelihood, likelihood

My understanding of the likelihood function is that it is insensitive to certain changes in parameters, ie if  ${\cal L}(x, y)$ is maximal for $\hat{x}$, $\hat{y}$, then ${\cal L}(z=f(x), y)$ is maximal for $\hat{z} = f(\hat{x})$, $\hat{y}$ (this probably assumes $f$ is monotonic).  I think this also holds for the asymptotic confidence intervals obtained by shifting the likelihood from its maximum.

But what if we make a change mixing the variables, eg if we take ${\cal L}(z=x/y, y)$, will it be maximal for $\hat{z} = \hat{x} / \hat{y}$?  What can we say about the asymptotic confidence intervals?

Comment: While the transform is one-to-one, the maximum likelihood is invariant (in the above sense) to parameterisation.

Comment: @Xi'an how would that apply to the confidence intervals?  If from ${\cal L}(x,y)$ you get $x_L, x_H, y_L, y_H$, what do you get for $z_L, z_H$?